# how to set all pixels of a range of HSV values to another value in openCV with python?

Tags: python, opencv

i am using OpenCV with python. i want to replace the range of color by "**white**" color.

color range:

```
HMin = 130
SMin = 65
VMin = 135
HMax = 200
SMax = 160
VMax = 255
```

i know how to replace specific pixel value to another value:

```
im[np.where((im == [20,78,90]).all(axis = 2))] = [0,0,100]
cv2.imwrite('output.png', im)
```

so, do you know how could i use this method to set **all pixels of a range** of HSV values instead of a specific pixel value to another value?

Comment: with cv2.inRange you get a binary image out of it, then you can do `im[binaryImage == 255] = [0,0,100]`

Comment: @api55 do you mean `HSV-img = cv2.cvtColor(original-img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    minR = np.array([HMin, SMin, VMin])
    maxR = np.array([HMax, SMax, VMax])
orange-mask = cv2.inRange(HSV-img, minR , maxR) original-img[orange-mask]=[0,0,100]
 `

Comment: Take a look to the answer, @Silencer did what I tried to say, with pictures and everything :) but what you said is more or less that, original-img[orange-mask > 0]=[0,0,100]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `inRange` to find the mask, then replace the origin image with other value.

The following is replace the GREEN range into RED.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread( "sunflower.jpg" )

## convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

## mask of green (36,0,0) ~ (70, 255,255)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 0, 0), (70, 255,255))
bak = img.copy()

# replace with red 
bak[mask > 0] = (0, 0, 255)

cv2.imwrite("bak.png", bak)
```

---

Some links:

1. [How to define a threshold value to detect only green colour objects in an image :Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483951/how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image/47483966#47483966)
2. [How to change the image color when the pixels hsv values are in specific ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865092/how-to-change-the-image-color-when-the-pixels-hsv-values-are-in-specific-ranges/52871759#52871759)